# Send a php complex type array via SOAP using Zend Lib and retrieving it with Android KSOAP2 client

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, associative-array, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to return an associative array in a PHP function. This function retrieves some data from MySQL and is published in a WebService using Zend Library.

This function looks like:

Functions.php

```
class Functions  
{
    /** 
    *
    * @return array 
    */  
    public function Function1()  
    {

        $con = new mysqli(server, user, pass, database);

        if ($con->connect_errno) {
            die(__FUNCTION__ . $con->connect_error);
        }


        $con->set_charset('utf8');
        $arrayRet = array();

        $query = 'select field1, field2, field3 from table1';

        if(!$result = $con->query($query)){
            die(__FUNCTION__ . $con->error);
        }

        while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
            $arrayRet[] = $row;

        $result->close();
        $con->close(); 

        return $arrayRet;

    }
}
```

Then I have another PHP file that lets me access the function via SOAP (using Zend Lib):

Server.php

```
<?php
  include 'Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover.php';  
  include 'Zend/Soap/Server.php';  
  include 'Functions.php';  

  if(isset($_GET['wsdl']))   
  {  
     $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();  
     $autodiscover->setClass('Functions');  
     $autodiscover->handle();  
  }   
  else   
  {  
     $server = new Zend_Soap_Server("http://localhost/webservice/Server.php?wsdl");  
     $server->setClass('Functions');  
     $server->handle();  
  }  
?>
```

So far everything looks quite normal. If i write a php client, i'm able to consume the webservice and access the returned array as follows:

```
<?php

$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://localhost/webservice/Server.php?wsdl');
$arrayRet = $client->Function1();

foreach($arrayRet as $row )  
{  
 ?>
    <b>Field1: </b><?php echo $row['field1']; ?><br>
    <b>Field2: </b><?php echo $row['field2']; ?><br>
    <b>Field3: </b><?php echo $row['field3']; ?><br>
<?php  
  }  
?>
```

Ok, now my problem is that i'm not writing a php client but a Android client. I'm using the ksoap2 library to achieve it. With this library i'm able to handle "normal arrays" with the pare key and value, following [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070642/1521115). Using his properies:

```
    SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;
    String key = category_list.getProperty("key").toString();
    String value = category_list.getProperty("value").toString();
```

But the response from the function above (if i copy the toString() result) looks like:

```
Function1Response
{
  return=
  [
   Map{
    item=anyType{key=field1; value=hello; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field2; value=web; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field3; value=service; };}, 

   Map{
    item=anyType{key=field1; value=hello2; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field2; value=web2; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field3; value=service2; };}, 

   Map{
    item=anyType{key=field1; value=hello3; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field2; value=web3; }; 
    item=anyType{key=field3; value=service3; };}
   ]; 
  }
```

I could iterate this response using key and value properties, but i think it would be much better (and efficient) if i could have a response like:

```
Function1Response
{
  return=
  [
   Map{
    item=anyType{field1=hello; }; 
    item=anyType{field2=web; }; 
    item=anyType{field3=service; };}, 

   Map{
    item=anyType{field1=hello2; }; 
    item=anyType{field2=web2; }; 
    item=anyTypefield3=service2; };}, 

   Map{
    item=anyType{field1=hello3; }; 
    item=anyType{field2=web3; }; 
    item=anyType{field3=service3; };}
   ]; 
  }
```

So i could retrive them like:

```
    SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;
    String field1 = category_list.getProperty("field1").toString();
    String field2 = category_list.getProperty("field2").toString();
    String field3 = category_list.getProperty("field3").toString();
```

Is that possible? I think it can be done somehow in the php server side. But i have no idea. I have been reading here and there but nobody seems to have this problem.. or a solution.

I'm sorry for the long post. I could give more code details or explain it better if i've been not clear enough.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: ok... i'm starting to think that it's not even possible. Right? Returning any php array i will always have the pair "value and key", and i will never be able to change his fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i did find the solution.

The function in the PHP server that will publish the result in the webservice looks like:

```
class Functions  
{
    /** 
    *
    * @return array 
    */  
    public function Function1()  
    { 

        $con = new mysqli(server, user, pass, database);

        if ($con->connect_errno) {
            die(__FUNCTION__ . $con->connect_error);
        }


        $con->set_charset('utf8');
        $arrayRet = array();

        $query = 'select field1, field2, field3 from table1';

        if(!$result = $con->query($query)){
            die(__FUNCTION__ . $con->error);
        }

        while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
            $myClass = new TestClass();
            $myClass->field1 = $row["field1"];
            $myClass->field2 = $row["field2"];
            $myClass->field3 = $row["field3"]; 
            array_push($arrayRet, $myClass);
        }


        $result->close();
        $con->close(); 

        return $arrayRet;

    }
}
```

I have previously created a class with all relevant attributes, as simple as:

TestClass.php

```
<?php
class TestClass 
{
    /**
    * @var string 
    */
    public $field1;

    /**
    * @var string 
    */
    public $field2;

    /**
    * @var string 
    */
    public $field3;

}

?>
```

So basically we're returning an array filed with all the different instances of this class as items.

Now, in the Android Client Side (always using ksoap2 library) i receive a response like:

```
Function1Response
{
  return=
  [
    Struct{field1=hello; field2=web; field3=service;  },
    Struct{field1=hello2; field2=web2; field3=service2; }, 
    Struct{field1=hello3; field2=web3; field3=service3;}
  ]; 
}
```

and i'm able to iterate it:

```
        //call
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //envelope response
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        //retrieve the first property, actually the array
                Vector result3 = (Vector) result.getProperty(0);

        //iterate
        Enumeration e=result3.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            //each object from the array its an Soap Element that contanins the properties defined in the php class
            SoapObject item=((SoapObject)e.nextElement());

            String field1 = item.getProperty("field1").toString();
            String field2 = item.getProperty("field2").toString();
            String field3 = item.getProperty("field3").toString();

            stringBuilder.append(
                    "Field1: " + codi + "\n"+ 
                    "Field2: "+ titol +"\n"+ 
                    "Field3: "+ descr +"\n"+
                    "******************************\n");
        }
```

And that's it... i hope it will be useful for someone else.
Thanks